Getting "griddb_python.GSException: [Name not found]" when trying to insert data into GridDB container using Python
I'm trying to use GridDB to insert some data into a container, but I keep getting an error when attempting to insert records. Below is the code I've written so far:
import griddb_python as griddb

try:
    # Connect to the GridDB cluster
    factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
    gridstore = factory.get_store({
        "host": "239.0.0.1",
        "port": 10001,
        "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
    })

    # Get the container 'SampleContainer'
    container = gridstore.get_container("SampleContainer")

    if container is None:
        print("Container not found!")
        exit()

    # Define row data
    row_data = ["ID001", "Alice", "New York", "Developer"]

    # Put data into the container
    container.put(row_data)

    print("Data inserted successfully!")

except griddb.GSException as e:
    print("Error occurred:", e)

I've Tried:

I've double-checked that the GridDB instance is running, and I'm using the correct IP address (239.0.0.1) and port (10001).
I created a container in GridDB called "SampleContainer" using the GridDB web console and confirmed that it exists.
I also tried using different container names, thinking maybe there's a naming issue, but the same error keeps appearing.
Looked into the GridDB Python Client documentation to make sure the code follows the right structure for container access and data insertion.

The Error I Got:
When I run the code, I get the following exception:
griddb_python.GSException: [Name not found] (Error code: 151505)

Here is the full traceback:
griddb_python.GSException: [Name not found]
at Store.get_container()
at griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
at main()

So can you give any insight what may go wrong ? Or any possible solution ?

Have you tried checking whether the container exists by using gridstore.get_container_info("SampleContainer") before calling get_container()? This might give you more specific information about whether the container is accessible or if there's a typo in the name.

well, I will try and let you know
